# How to implement fixed header / footer in jQuery Mobile in Jan 2012

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

So now (Jan 2012) that **true fixed toolbars have been implemented** in jQuery Mobile (check the [blog entry](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/) and an [example](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/css-fixed/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)), it's still not available to download (as far as I know).

I already have fixed toolbars in my app but the old way (toolbars move with Javascript). What are the **steps** I need **to take to** convert an app in jQuery Mobile to **have these new fixed toolbars** implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following steps will make it work:

1. Download the jQuery Mobile Javascript file from the css-fixed branch
   ([here](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/css-fixed/js/))
   and default theme CSS file from the same branch ([here](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/css-fixed/css/themes/default/))
   and put them somewhere inside your project folder.
2. Replace your
   references in HTML (probably index.html) from old files (usually
   something like jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js and
   jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css) with these two downloaded files.

This should now work. At least it works for me on an iPad with iOS 5.0. But make sure that the faux fixed toolbars worked for you before, the instructions are [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following imports

[js](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/css-fixed/js/)
[css](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/css-fixed/css/themes/default/)

Comment: Well you can try with the latest nightly build and use the fixed css code to your navigation bar manually instead of using fixed=true.

Answer (score 0):

true fixed toolbars have NOT been fully implemented till now. there are still some main issues in that. Check out http://jquerymobile.com/blog/ 
so, i guess u'll have to wait for jquery mobile 1.1 as the blog says.

Comment: yes i read your question. but the true fixed toolbars r not there yet.
are u asking HOW to to implement them yourself in jquery mobile?

Comment: You are saying that I will have to wait for JQM 1.1 and also that true fixed toolbars are not there yet. These two statements do not go together cause true fixed toolbars are now probably in the same state in the development version as they will be in the release version. If you read my question and the blog, than maybe you are not aware that the JQM code is on github and we can get the development version right now?... And yes, I've tried the demo I posted on an iPad with iOS 5.0 and it works. Now.